# Getting undefined with strict equality operator but not with normal equality operator

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
function sym(...args) {
  let arr = [...args];

  while(!arr.length === 0) {
      arr.pop();
      console.log(arr.length);
  }
}

console.log(sym([1,2,5],[2,3,5],[3,4,5]));
```

I was trying to figure one problem out but another problem came up. Can someone please explain to me why this logs undefined? The strict equality operator logs undefined but the normal equality operator doesn't, even though `arr.length` returns a number.

Comment: `!arr.length === 0` will evaluate to either `false === 0` or `true === 0`, which are both `false`, so your while loop never runs. You likely want `while(arr.length !== 0)`

Comment: You return nothing from the `sym`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`!` has higher operator precedence than `===`.

```
while(!arr.length === 0) {
```

is equivalent to

```
while((!arr.length) === 0) {
```

Comparing a boolean to a number will never work with `===`, but it will sometimes work with `==` - but either way, that isn't what you want. Use `!== 0` instead.

```js
function sym(...args) {
  let arr = [...args];

  while(arr.length !== 0) {
      arr.pop();
  }
  return arr;
}

console.log(sym([1,2,5],[2,3,5],[3,4,5]));
```

Comment: So what you're saying is `while((!arr.length) === 0)` is basically `while(false === 0)` which will never be true with the strict equality operator because the types are different? And the reason it returns false is because `!arr.length` will never be true as long as something's in the array?

Comment: Also `while(!(arr.length === 0))` gives me the same as the code you suggested above. Can this be used or would you still recommend the way you first did it?

Comment: Both work, but `arr.length !== 0` is easier to grasp when reading the code, I think. "While the length is not 0" compared to "While *not* 'the length is equal to 0'"